# Good practices: valid property vs. isValid() method?

Tags: java, validation

Which approach of checking beeing valid is better? The first one:

```
public class Order {
    ...
    private boolean valid;

    public boolean isValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    public boolean setValid(boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }

    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

where `valid` is kept as boolean in DB and set by Java code somewhere else, e.g. in DAO.

Or the second one:

```
public class Order {
    ...


    public boolean isValid() {
        // some business code, e.g.:
        return !orderItems.isEmpty();
    }


    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

where we don't have `valid` value keeped in DB, but everytime when it's needed it is been calculated on demand.

Which approach is better?

Comment: I think the second approach is better. Hitting your database is generally more expensive than some simple computation.

Comment: But `orderItems` also belongs to this entity, and to database, so everytime we compute `isValid()` we use many properties of database.

Comment: I don't know if you are using Spring Framework, but there is some interesting information about validation in their docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: Checking validity in a method is better than storing it in a variable.  I couldn't care less what the valid value is unless I want to access it, in which case I would call the method.  It also means the result is good because it is calculated when I call the method, and is not stale data.  That said, with the two implementations, you could name them the same and nobody without visibility into your class would know the difference

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you are treating 'valid' as a POJO field, ie just like a **getter()** or **setter()** method, except because it is boolean it is an **isser()** method. This is OK, as I would not break this bean-like pattern. Getters and setters should have no logic behind them.

Insetad I would have another method **validate()** which does the heavy stuff.

validate() performs the validation and sets the valid variable. isValid() returns the last validation performed.

An antipattern I often see is a **getXXXXX()** method which takes about 30 seconds to complete because it is performing calculations and database hits, confusing the user of this class as the user assumes it is a normal getter in a normal POJO class.

Answer (score 1):

There's no exact answer. It just depends. Depends on the design of your class and the business rules of your business.

For example, if the `valid` state of an order only checks for a simple rule like checking the current state of the object reference, then have it as a method with a body.

```
public class Order {
    public boolean isValid() {
        //validate current state of object reference
        //re using your same example
        return !orderDetail.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

But in the case you have a business rule that demands the order should pass for a validation process before sending it to the client and this status (and a proper description) should be known at any moment of the application, then having a `valid` field in database is one way to solve it. In fact, if this was the case, it would be even better to store the `valid` field as a `VARCHAR(X)` and limit the values of this field by using an `enum OrderStatus`. But then again, this depends on the design for your class.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt structure with `setValid` method is ugly. I can not imagine the usage of `setValid` method.
If you want to use separate property, the better way is to use lazy initialization:

```
public class Order 
{
    ...
    private Boolean valid;

    public boolean isValid() 
    {
        if (valid == null)
        {
           valid = !orderItems.isEmpty();
        }
        // some business code, e.g.:
        return valid;
    }
}
```

If `isValid` method contains hard logic **and your class is immutable** (*orderItems* is a constant) then you can use this variant.
In other cases second variant is better.

Comment: Note that with this code, you need to reset the 'valid' field when 'orderItems' changes!

Comment: What if `valid` depends on many properties of Order class? And when we change another property we want method `isValid()` to still work properly

Comment: This would be valid if `Order` class is immutable.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thank you for correction. I have added it to answer

Comment: If it is immutable, then I would validate it in the constructor to avoid creating an invalid instance in the first place.

Comment: In order to this class to become immutable, `orderItems` should not only be constant but immutable as well. For example, I have `final List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();` and its *constant* because I cannot reassign the value of `intList` but I can still modify its state, this is, add and remove elements.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You cann't modify `ArrayList` if it's *true* immutable class.

Comment: You cannot modify the instance, this is, reassign, but you can still call `intList.add(5); intList.add(10); intList.clear();` (taking `intList` from previous comment) and this compiles and runs with no problems.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if getter looks like `getList(){return Collection.unmodifiableList(list)};` (like in *true* immutable class) then cann't

Comment: That's not truly immutable, and you're creating an unmodifiable list per `get` call. It would be better to assign the list as unmodifiable on the class constructor.